# How do I get ANTLRWorks working?

Tags: linux, antlrworks

By following [How do I install this damn thing? on](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=728) www.antlr.org I have got ANTLR 3.5 to work:

```
$ java -version    # I have Oracle`s Java JDK installed
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
$ ls
antlrworks-1.5.jar
$ export CLASSPATH=./antlrworks-1.5.jar:$CLASSPATH
$ java org.antlr.Tool -version
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 3.5
```

But according to [ANTLRWorks: The ANTLR GUI Development Environment](http://www.antlr.org/works/), **ANTLRWorks should also be included in the above JAR file. How do I start it?**

---

If I type `java a` and double tab it first completes it to `java antlr.` indicating that there is no antlrworks package on the classpath. I don't know if there should be one. If I keep double tabbing I get:

```
antlr.ANTLRException                     antlr.CharStreamIOException              antlr.debug.ListenerBase                 antlr.debug.TraceListener                antlr.SemanticException
antlr.ANTLRHashString                    antlr.collections.AST                    antlr.debug.MessageEvent                 antlr.DefaultFileLineFormatter           antlr.StringUtils
antlr.ANTLRStringBuffer                  antlr.collections.ASTEnumeration         antlr.debug.MessageListener              antlr.FileLineFormatter                  antlr.Token
antlr.ASTFactory                         antlr.collections.impl.ASTArray          antlr.debug.ParserListener               antlr.InputBuffer                        antlr.TokenBuffer
antlr.ASTNULLType                        antlr.collections.impl.ASTEnumerator     antlr.debug.ParserMatchEvent             antlr.LexerSharedInputState              antlr.TokenQueue
antlr.ASTPair                            antlr.collections.impl.BitSet            antlr.debug.ParserMatchListener          antlr.LLkParser                          antlr.TokenStream
antlr.BaseAST                            antlr.collections.impl.IntRange          antlr.debug.ParserTokenEvent             antlr.MismatchedCharException            antlr.TokenStreamException
antlr.ByteBuffer                         antlr.collections.impl.Vector            antlr.debug.ParserTokenListener          antlr.MismatchedTokenException           antlr.TokenStreamIOException
antlr.CharBuffer                         antlr.collections.impl.VectorEnumerator  antlr.debug.SemanticPredicateEvent       antlr.NoViableAltException               antlr.TokenStreamRecognitionException
antlr.CharFormatter                      antlr.CommonAST                          antlr.debug.SemanticPredicateListener    antlr.NoViableAltForCharException        antlr.TreeParser
antlr.CharQueue                          antlr.CommonToken                        antlr.debug.SyntacticPredicateEvent      antlr.Parser                             antlr.TreeParserSharedInputState
antlr.CharScanner                        antlr.debug.Event                        antlr.debug.SyntacticPredicateListener   antlr.ParserSharedInputState             antlr.Utils
antlr.CharStreamException                antlr.debug.GuessingEvent                antlr.debug.TraceEvent                   antlr.RecognitionException
```

---

I downloaded `antlrworks-1.5.jar` by visiting http://www.antlr.org/download.html and clicking [Version 1.5 - for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlrworks-1.5.jar). The JAR's file size is `2684608` bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this answer is too simple

1) Go to the [antlrworks](http://www.antlr.org/works/) site and download the [antlrworks](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlrworks-1.5.jar) file

2) cd to your download folder, and: `java -jar antlrworks-1.5.jar`

Comment: The people here at SO and in paticular for the Antlr tag want the answers that with links to include the info from the link in the answer in case the link no longer provides the same info or becomes broken. Welcome to SO and don't be afarid to answer. Just take this as friendly advise. Some people may down vote your answer becuase of the missing info, but I prefer to just inform the new people. :)

Comment: Thanks! I had a bad case of stupidity (I don´t know if I´ve still got it).

Comment: @Matt It is ok to edit your question with info from someone else's answer here as it is all Creative Commons. Just be sure to note that you pulled the info from the other person. This is especailly important if you get the accepted answer and the OP notes that there is better information in another answer. It is for the benefit of those that follow who only look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://www.antlr3.org/download/ instead of http://www.antlr3.org/download.html
Notice no html on the end.

Now you can see the actual sizes of the files.

The AntlrWorks jar includes Antlr, but the Antlr jar does not include AntlrWorks.

Once you have the Antlrworks jar on your system and **[Sun Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml)** installed.

See: http://www.antlr3.org/works/help/tutorial/howtorun.html

> Run on Linux
>
> To run ANTLRWorks, use the command-line: •$ java -jar
>   antlrworks-1.2.1.jar •
>
> Note: On Linux, make sure the Sun JDK is installed. Any other JDK is
>   not supported as many of them simply crashes when Swing is invoked.

Yes the documenation is out of date. Just use the correct name for the jar file.

Remember that this is all free software and maintained by people on their own time so the older stuff does not get updated as much as it should. :)

Comment: Your answer is more informative, but I´ll throw the bone to the new guy for being first. I had a bad case of stupidity (I don´t know if I´ve still got it).

Answer (score 0):

New url to get antlrworks-1.5 (antlr 3.0 with gui) : http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlrworks-1.5.jar
(antlr.org is now dedicated to antlr 4.0....)

Comment: Since all of the content at Stack Exchange is Creative Commons, feel free to edit the links if they become broken. I for one don't mind people editing my answers.